# SQL wont insert data but connects to db?

Tags: php, sql, database, insert

I have been attempting this for hours to no avail, my code tells me I have connected successfully, but when I click register the page just refreshes, I check my database with no changes, I have tried several different online scripts to maybe check if it was my code, that has not worked, I updated my godaddy SQL version, still changed nothing..?

Im hoping someone can tell me what im doing wrong, thank you, here is the code im using.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username="****";
$password="*****";
$dbname="****";
try{
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username,$password,$dbname);
echo("successful in connection");
}catch(MySQLi_Sql_Exception $ex){
echo("error in connection");
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$register_query = "INSERT INTO `users`('email`, `username`, `password`) VALUES ('$email','$username','$password')";
try{
$register_result = mysqli_query($conn, $register_query);
if($register_result){
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0){
echo("registration successful");
}else{
echo("error in registration");
}

}
}catch(Exception $ex){
echo("error".$ex->getMessage());
}
}

?>

<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Register</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body  id="fullBg">



<div class="container">
    <form class="form-signin"  id="login-register"  method="post" action="">
      <h1 class="form-signin-heading">Join The Club</h1>
      <div style="margin:auto; width:135px; height:135px; background-color:grey; margin-bottom:15px; border-radius:50%;">
        <br>

      </div>
        <input style="" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" placeholder="Username" />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" />
        <input style="margin:0px; margin-bottom:15px;" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="inputPassword"  placeholder="Password" />

  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ppemail" value="<?php echo $ppemail; ?>" placeholder="Paypal Email"/>
<br>
      <button class="logo-button btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
  <a  href="/login.php"><p class="text-center sign-up" style="color:black !important;">Back To <strong>Login</strong></p></a>
  <?php if(isset($smsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <?php echo $smsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please note that you’re directly putting user given values to SQL strings. This makes you vulnerable to SQL injections as well as easily breaks everything if anyone happens to put a ‘ in the data. Use parameters/prepared statements.

Comment: Im aware, but the issue is it wont even post to mySQL so not like theres any danger xD

Comment: So you know it’s wrong, do it anyway, and then wonder why there’s problems? Doesn’t seem logical

Answer (score 0):

put this `var_dump($register_query);exit;` after this line:

```
$register_result = mysqli_query($conn, $register_query);
```

and then check the sql or just run the sql directly(by logining into mysql in command line, or use phpmyadmin, or some GUI client like [mysql workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) or Navicat for mysql and so on...)